# ZF2 Zend Tool CLI will not work on Mac

Tags: php, macos, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-tool

I am attempting to use Zend Tool in the Zend Framework 2 with no luck.  I have installed it with composer in a project directory, and executed the composer install command. This appears to be successful.  I have also downloaded the zftool.phar file.  When I attempt a command with zf.php or zftool.php I get a failure message:

-bash: zf.php: command not found

But I am in the directory where zf.php is located.  I also tried copying zftool.phar to my usr/sbin folder but still receive the command not found message.  I have Googled for over an hour and cannot find any solution to this.

If anyone has a clue what I am doing wrong I would greatly appreciate some feedback.  Admittedly I am an amateur at this.

I am running OS X 10.8.4.

Comment: make sure zf.php and php in your path

Answer (score 0):

It tells you the **command** zf.php is not found. It doesn't even look for a file at this point. To use zftool.phar you need to be able to run PHP in your CLI.

To check if PHP is enabled in your CLI type the following:

```
php --version
```

It should output something like this:

```
PHP 5.3.26 (cli) (built: Jun  5 2013 19:16:29) Copyright (c) 1997-2013
The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend
Technologies
```

Also you have to install/enable the PHAR module for PHP. http://php.net/manual/en/book.phar.php

Now change dir (cd) to where zftool.phar is located and use the zftool.phar like this:

```
php zftool.phar create project foo
```